# Why does RichTextBox stop working in unit tests?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, richtextbox

I have recently run into an issue that has left me very confused.  I have a C# 4.0 Winform project that I was originally using only TextBoxes.  My problem started when I switched from a TextBox to a RichTextBox and my unit tests started failing.

My first thought was that the compiler was confused by changing the variable's object type. So I tried a clean build and that did not work.  A co-worker even suggested a windows update and restart, but the problem still persists.

I tracked the problem down to the fact that the RichTextBox's TextChanged event is not firing.  Upon more investigation, I found that before I subscribe to the TextChanged event if I open the RichTextBox object up in debug mode and simply look at it - the test will pass.  But I do not want to have to examine an object in debug mode every time I run the tests!

I find this to be really curious.  I also found that running the program normally results in everything running smoothly.  I am quite sure the issue is that the unit tests don't actually open up the UI; only the Form object is used.

This is the first Control that I've seen experience this problem.  That's what makes this so strange.  What's more perplexing to me is that RichTextBox and TextBox both extend TextBoxBase.  In my main program I have DataGridViews, ListBoxes, and TextBoxes working just fine in these unit tests, but for some reason RichTextBox breaks down.

Can anyone explain why RichTextBox base needs the UI active when so many other Controls do not?

I've refined the code down to just show the problem parts:

The Observer class observes the TextBox and RichTextBox, and updates a struct object anytime there is a change to the TextBoxes.  If I examine the richTextBox parameter in debug mode before subscribing to the TextChanged event, the unit test will pass.

```
public class Observer {
    public DataStruct dataStructCopy { get; set; }
    private TextBoxBase textBox { get; set; }
    private TextBoxBase richTextBox { get; set; } 

    public Observer(DataStruct dataStruct, TextBoxBase textBox, TextBoxBase richTextBox) {
        this.dataStructCopy = new DataStruct(dataStruct.textBoxText, dataStruct.richTextBoxText);
        this.textBox = textBox;
        this.richTextBox = richTextBox;

        this.textBox.TextChanged += (o, e) => { this.dataStructCopy.textBoxText = textBox.Text; };
        this.richTextBox.TextChanged += (o, e) => { this.dataStructCopy.richTextBoxText = richTextBox.Text; };
    }
}
```

And here's how I test my code:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    private View view { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize() {
        this.view = new View();
    }

    //This method passes.
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTextBox() {
        string text = "text";
        view.getTextBox().Text = text;
        Assert.AreEqual(text, view.getTextBox().Text);
    }

    //This method passes.
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRichTextBox() {
        string text = "text";
        view.getRichTextBox().Text = text;
        Assert.AreEqual(text, view.getRichTextBox().Text);
    }

    //This method fails.
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestObserver() {
        string text = "text";
        string richText = "rich";

        view.getTextBox().Text = text;
        view.getRichTextBox().Text = richText;

        Assert.AreEqual(text, view.observer.dataStructCopy.textBoxText);//this works
        Assert.AreEqual(richText, view.observer.dataStructCopy.richTextBoxText);//this fails
    }
}
```

I am trying to show two things here.  Firstly, I have been able to successfully test other Controls before without actually loading the UI.  I am also trying to show that the RichTextBox is able to handle the change to its Text property - the problem is with its TextChanged event as evidenced by the failure of the DataStruct to update.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Testing the GUI this way will only work for the simplest of properties. As soon as something does Gethandle() it will break. Use UI test tools to thest the UI.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for the reply! I am not familiar with the Gethandle method, is there somewhere that I can read more about it?

Comment: It's in the Control class. And in google-space.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks!  That's all I needed to know.